# Why is $H_\delta^d$ monotone decreasing in $\delta$ in the definition of Hausdorff measure?

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

In trying to understand the definition of Hausdorff dimension I'm trying to get a good understanding of Hausdorff measure. On wikipedia they first make the following definition ([found here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure):

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $S$ be any subset of $X$ and $\delta>0$
>   be a real number, then define
>
> $H_{\delta }^{d}(S)=\inf {\Bigl \{}\sum _{{i=1}}^{\infty
>  }(\operatorname {diam}\;U_{i})^{d}:\bigcup _{{i=1}}^{\infty
>  }U_{i}\supseteq S,\,\operatorname {diam}\;U_{i}<\delta {\Bigr \}}$.

Then we take $\lim_{\delta\to 0} H_{\delta }^{d}(S)$ as a definition of $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

What I am stuck on right now is the motivation for this limit that they give saying:

*"Note that $H_{\delta }^{d}(S)$ is monotone decreasing in $\delta$, since the larger $\delta$ is, the more collections of sets are permitted, making the infimum smaller."*

As I understand it we are taking the infimum over a set of sums of all the diameters of each set in a cover. Now say we increase $\delta$ so that we can cover $S$ with a $\delta$-ball. Then how is increasing $\delta$ even more going to permit a cover with an even smaller "total diameter" than before? I might have forgotten or misunderstood something trivial but I don't see why the infimum would necessarily change by allowing "bigger" sets in the covers.

**In conclusion my question is:**

Q: Will someone give an explanation to why the statement made in the above quotation is true (and/or preferably give some intuition for it)?

*(My level is undergraduate.*)

Comment: Any cover ${U_i}$ in which each set has diameter less than $\delta$ is also a cover in which each set has diameter less than $\delta^\prime$, where $\delta^\prime<\delta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\delta_1 < \delta_2$.

The family $\mathcal{U}_{\delta_2}=\left\{ U \mid \bigcup _{i=1}^{\infty
 }U_{i}\supseteq S,\,\operatorname{diam}(U_{i})<\delta_2 \right\}$ contains the family $\mathcal{U}_{\delta_1}=\left\{ U \mid \bigcup _{i=1}^{\infty
 }U_{i}\supseteq S,\,\operatorname{diam}(U_{i})<\delta_1 \right\}$. Indeed, is $U \in \mathcal{U}_{\delta_1}$, then $\operatorname{diam}(U) < \delta_1 < \delta_2$, so $U \in \mathcal{U}_{\delta_2}$.

Then, taking the infimum over $\mathcal{U}_{\delta_2}$ leads to something possibly smaller than taking it over $\mathcal{U}_{\delta_1}$ (this is just set theory).

The last sentence can be reread as $H_{\delta_2 }^{d}(S) \leq  H_{\delta_1 }^{d}(S)$, so we have proved that, given $\delta_1 < \delta_2$, we have $H_{\delta_1 }^{d}(S) \geq H_{\delta_2 }^{d}(S)$, so $H_{\delta}^{d}(S)$ is decreasing in $\delta$.

Comment: Silly =). Of course, it does not have to be strictly decreasing. I just think my mind was set on that or something. The important thing is that it can not increase which make sense. The key word was of course 'possibly'. Quick follow-up: Will $H_\delta^d(S)$, as a function of $d$, always jump directly from $\infty$ to $0$ for some $d$, if so then why?

Comment: That's a great question. There is _at most_ one integer $d$ for which $H^d_{\delta}(S) \in (0, \infty)$. Then it's always $0$ for $d' > d$, and $\infty$ for $d' <d$. If such an integer exists, it is called the [Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) of $S$. However, you can define Hausdorff measure for any nonnegative real number $s$ instead of $d$, and in that case there will exists exactly one, the Hausdorff dimension, which needs not be an integer.

Comment: Yes, I think the picture is becoming clearer now. What I was trying to see was merely why there could only be at most one integer $d$ for which $H^d_{\delta}(S) \in (0, \infty)$ (namely, for 'ordinary' geometrical objects, corresponding to the topological dimension) as you mention, but I think I got a better intuition for that as well. Thank you.